# Is it possible to create a cascading dropdown in an inline edit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

While changing Country in dropdown relevant states is not displaying.. alert gets very first country id each time while selecting different countries

```
<span editable-select="user.Country" e-name="Countrychk" e-id="Country" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="x._id as x.CountryName for x in Countrydata"e-ng-change="changeCountry(user.Country)">{{ Countrydata.CountryName }}
```

```
$http.get('/CountryDetails').then(function(response){
    debugger;
    $scope.Countrydata=response.data;
});
$scope.changeCountry=function(CountryID){
    debugger;
    alert(CountryID);
    $http.get('/StateDetails1'+ CountryID).then(function(response){
        $scope.Statedata = response.data;
        console.log($scope.Statedata);
    });
};
```